# Check if a string starts with a number in parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex

My title can look like

```
(10) - lorem ipsum
(101) - lorem ipsum
(1) - lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
```

I want to check if my title contains `(number)` at the start

```
string.match(/^(+[0-9]+)+$/);
```

I'm not good on regex, can someone help and say what is wrong ?

Comment: If you want to just check, use `RegExp.test()` rather than `String.match()` unless you need the value itself.

Comment: Adam's answer should be correct, will require `(` to be first character on the string, followed by 1 or more numbers and then `)`. @WiktorStribiżew I usually use this idiom; `if(  /^\[0-9]+\)/.test(string)  )`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just remove the `$` from your regex, and escape the parentheses.

```
string.match(/^\([0-9]+\)/);
```

`$` means end of string.

`(` and `)` are special character and should be escaped. Pharenthesis are used for grouping. You can find a list of special characters [here](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Regular_expressions_1__Special_characters.html).

Comment: You could event use `\d`. Also, it would be useful to explain *why* you escaped the parenthesis :)

Answer (score 0):

Use test method to return whether condition is true or false, Whether it starting with number or not.

```
/^\([0-9]+\)/.test(string);
```

OR

```
var patt = new RegExp(/^\([0-9]+\)/);
patt.test(string);
```